# Forcing erl -make to recompile files when macros are changed

Tags: erlang, makefile

I tried to do something similar to [How to make two different source directories in a Makefile output to one bin directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894363/how-to-make-two-different-source-directories-in-a-makefile-output-to-one-bin-dire/1895096#1895096), so I have these files (relative to my project root):

```
Emakefile:
% EMakefile
% -*- mode: erlang -*-
{["src/*", "src/*/*", "src/*/*/*"],
 [{i, "include"}, {outdir, "ebin"}, debug_info]}.

test/Emakefile:
% EMakefile
% -*- mode: erlang -*-
{["../src/*", "../src/*/*", "../src/*/*/*"],
 [{i, "../include"}, {outdir, "../ebin"}, debug_info, {d, 'TEST'}]}.

Makefile:
EPATH=-pa ebin

all: before_compile
    erl -make

all_test: before_compile
    cd test
    erl -make
    cd ..

before_compile: mk_ebin copy_sqlite create_db copy_config copy_dot_app

test: all_test
    erl -noshell $(EPATH) \
        -s tests run \
        -s init stop
    rm -f ct.db

clean:
    rm -fv ebin/*

... dependencies of before_compile
```

The problem is that running `make test` doesn't recompile any modules which are already compiled with `make`. It seems `erl -make` doesn't care that they were compiled without `TEST` defined, it just checks that the modules themselves are older than beam-files. How do I force it to recompile (and avoid recompilation when it isn't needed)?

**UPDATE**: Strangely, when running `make all_test` immediately after `make clean`, it appears that `./Emakefile` is used instead of `test/Emakefile`: I am getting

```
Recompile: src/tests
Recompile: src/server_protocol_client
```

etc. and no tests instead of

```
Recompile: ../src/tests
Recompile: ../src/server_protocol_client
```

which I get by doing `cd test; erl -make` manually. Any idea why? Anyway, I've fixed this problem by removing `test/Emakefile` and replacing `all_test` in `Makefile`:

```
all_test: before_compile
    erl -noshell -eval "make:all([{d, 'TEST'}])." -s init stop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all_test: before_compile
    cd test
    erl -make
    cd ..
```

This is incorrect. Each line produces its own process. Do such:

```
all_test: before_compile
    cd test; \
    erl -make
```